# How to open the QuickBooks Desktop UI and prefill an invoice with items?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm using `Intuit QuickBooks Pro 2015`.

With `QBXMLRP2` and with the following `XML` file I can open the `QuickBooks` UI and prefill a new invoice with the desired customer, on this case: `George Clooney`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="4.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <TxnDisplayAddRq requestID = "1">
            <TxnDisplayAddType>Invoice</TxnDisplayAddType>
            <EntityRef>
                <FullName>George Clooney</FullName>
            </EntityRef>
        </TxnDisplayAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Until here everything is OK.

My problem is that I need to add items to this invoice.

Then, I try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="4.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <TxnDisplayAddRq requestID = "1">
            <TxnDisplayAddType>Invoice</TxnDisplayAddType>
            <EntityRef>
                <FullName>George Clooney</FullName>
            </EntityRef>
            <InvoiceLineAdd>
                <Desc>For the house</Desc>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <Rate>120.00</Rate>
            </InvoiceLineAdd>
        </TxnDisplayAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

but I get the following error:

```
Exception: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.
```

On the Programmer's Guide I don't find the way to do this:

https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBSDK_ProGuide.pdf

Here are the available XML examples:

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK13_Samples/tree/master/xmlfiles/legacy

For my example I used specifically, the file: `TxnDisplayAdd_Invoice.xml`.

**My question:** How do I add items to this new invoice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to the QuickBooks OSR for qbXML reference:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

The supported XML request nodes look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <TxnDisplayAddRq>
      <!-- TxnDisplayAddType may have one of the following values: Bill, BillPayment, BuildAssembly, Charge, Check, CreditCardCharge, CreditCardCredit, CreditMemo, Deposit, Estimate, InventoryAdjustment, Invoice, ItemReceipt, JournalEntry, PurchaseOrder, ReceivePayment, SalesOrder, SalesReceipt, SalesTaxPaymentCheck, VendorCredit -->
      <TxnDisplayAddType >ENUMTYPE</TxnDisplayAddType> <!-- required -->
      <EntityRef> <!-- optional -->
        <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
        <FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
      </EntityRef>
    </TxnDisplayAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

In short - you can't do what you're trying to do. QuickBooks doesn't support it.

The only thing you can pre-fill is the entity (customer).